# Can not show content html in webview Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using webview to display content html in database, but have an error when display

**my code**

```
public void showData(){
    String title = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" /></head><body><h2 class=\"title\">" + article.getTitle()+ "</h2>\n";
    String timeAgo = "<div class=\"date_time_post\"><span class=\"date\">" + article.getYear() + "</span></div>";
    String content ="<div class=\"content\">" + article.getContent() + "</div></body></html>";

    String text = title + timeAgo + content;
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

[this is the error result when display](https://gyazo.com/c7c7c33ab0dc048a55c68b83af42e716)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: this is error https://gyazo.com/c7c7c33ab0dc048a55c68b83af42e716

Comment: i cant access above link, can you please post error here

Comment: you can append html content to "text" variable which works for you.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
webView.loadData(text, "text/html", null);
```

instead of

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: because I need load a .css file in assets folder, therefore I used webView.loadDataWithBaseURL. Just try using loadData but still error

Comment: if you are still searching for way.. what you can do is 
1)create new html file with your generated html code and store it to the external/internal phone memory. 
2) in same directory copy your style.css file from the assets. and then load the html file from the memory.